# React Native State Updated when it should not

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, mapping, use-state

I have `filterData` which comes from a controller, so i set `filterData` to options, for the UI,
Like this

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    options: filterData,
  });
```

filter data is this

```
[{"List": [{"Name": "TEST1", "isSelected": false}, {"Name": "TEST2", "isSelected": false}, {"Name": "TEST3", "isSelected": true}], "Type": "Type"},
{"List": [{"Name": "TEST4", "isSelected": false}, {"Name": "TEST5", "isSelected": false}, {"Name": "TEST6", "isSelected": true}], "Type": "Type2"}]
```

I render it in a `flatlist` and then `map` the List, this is the code for my `flatlist`

```
 <FlatList
        style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.white}}
        data={state.options}
        keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          return (
            <View style={{marginBottom: widthPercentageToDP(5)}}>
              <Text>
                {item.Type}
              </Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  flexWrap: 'wrap',
                }}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    marginRight: 8,
                    marginBottom: 8,
                  }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>
                      Select All
                    </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                {item.List.map((e: any, idx: number) => (
                  <View
                    key={idx}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      onPress={() =>
                        handleSelect(idx, item.Type)
                      }
                     >
                      <Text>
                        {e.Name}
                      </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                ))}
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }}
        </View>
      </View>
      );
     }}
   />
```

as you can see from above, i will have some `buttons`. And if the `button` is clicked, it will call `handleSelect` function. which is this

```
const handleSelect = async (idx: number, type: string) => {
    let arr = [...state.options];

    arr.map((item) => {
      if (item.Type === type) {
        item.List[idx].isSelected = !item.List[idx].isSelected;
      }
    });

    console.log(state.options)
  };
```

i didnt change the state of the options like the code below, only console.log

```
setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      options: arr,
    }));
```

The problem is, in the log when i clicked and run that function, `state.options` will also change.
it will have the same data as `arr`. Even `filterData` also change when i `console.log` in `handleselect`. I already checked my controller and it didnt trigger any function.
Does anyone know why it update all of my variable?

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem: Mutating State

When you create a copied array like `let arr = [...state.options];`, the variable `arr` is a new array, but the elements of that array are references to the same objects as in the original `state.options`.  So when you toggle `isSelected` on an element of `arr`, you are also changing the value in your state.

This line is the where the mutation occurs:

```
item.List[idx].isSelected = !item.List[idx].isSelected;
```

Your `arr.map()` doesn't actually return anything.  `.map()` is meant to map an element to a new value so your callback needs to return the new value.  You probably meant to use `.forEach()`.  We actually do want `.map()` though, but we need to return the `item`.

As a sidenote, you can have multiple `useState` hooks per component so you don't need to use object properties like you would in a class component.  What you have is not a problem, but you can make it simpler:

```
const [options, setOptions] = React.useState(filterData);
```

#### Solution: Replace the Object

You need to create a copied object for any objects where you are changing properties.  You don't actually need to copy the whole array because `.map` already returns a copy.

```
const handleSelect = async (idx: number, type: string) => {
  setOptions(options.map((item) => {
    if (item.Type === type) {
      // return a copy
      return {
        ...item,
        // replace the whole List property with a mapped copy
        List: item.List.map( (obj, i) => {
          if ( i === idx ) {
            // return a copy with a new value of isSelected
            return {
              ...obj,
              isSelected: !obj.isSelected,
            }
          } else {
            // return the same item
            return obj;
          }
        }
        )
      };
    } else {
      // return the same item
      return item;
    }
  }));
};
```

The mapping is complicated because you have an object within an array within an object within an array.  You might want to store your selections separate from that messy structure.

We can make the mapping shorter by using the ternary operator instead of `if`/`else`.

```
const handleSelect = async (idx: number, type: string) => {
    setOptions(
      options.map((item) =>
        item.Type === type
          ? {
              ...item,
              List: item.List.map((obj, i) =>
                i === idx
                  ? {
                      ...obj,
                      isSelected: !obj.isSelected
                    }
                  : obj
              )
            }
          : item
      )
    );
  };
```